# Can someone explain why my counter won"t decrease

Tags: ruby, increment

So the question is asking me to represent the hunger level of different people ranging from 0 to 5 after giving out N sandwiches which will range from 1 to 20. The format of the array will be [N, h1, h2, h3, ...] the rest of the array will represent the hunger levels of different people.My goal is to minimize the hunger difference between each pair of people in the array using the sandwiches I have available.

So my plan was to go through each element and subtract the difference from the next element which works but i don't know why it won't decrease my sandwich counter.

```
def FoodDistribution(arr)
  sandwiches = arr[0]

  2.upto(arr.length - 1) do |i|
      arr[1] -= arr[1] - arr[2] if arr[1] > arr[2] 
      if arr[i] > arr[i - 1] && arr[0] > 0
          arr[i] -= (arr[i] - arr[i - 1])
          arr[0] -= (arr[i] - arr[i - 1])
      end
 end
 return arr

end
```

Comment: Usually "minimization" problems involve permutation, which means somewhere [`permutation`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation) should come into play. Note that `sandwiches` here is defined, but never used?

Answer (score 1):

Change it so that you are subtracting from the sandwiches first:

```
def FoodDistribution(arr)
    sandwiches = arr[0

    2.upto(arr.length - 1) do |i|
    arr[1] -= arr[1] - arr[2]

    if arr[1] > arr[2] 
        if arr[i] > arr[i - 1] && arr[0] > 0
            arr[0] = arr[0] - (arr[i] - arr[i - 1])
            arr[i] -= (arr[i] - arr[i - 1])
        end
    end

    return arr
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I reccommend posting the entire problem so that we can see the problem in context.  I'm not sure what the 'correct' way to solve the problem, however...the counter is not decrementing because of these two lines in your if conditional..:

```
arr[i] -= (arr[i] - arr[i - 1])
```

this line effectively sets both arr[i] and arr[i]- 1 to the same value. example:

```
x = 3
y = 4
y -= (y - x) ## y - x = 1
y == 3
```

So arr[i] and arr[i - 1] are now the same.  their difference is zero.. in the next line, you subtract this difference (0), from N, thus N does not decrement.

```
arr[0] -= (arr[i] - arr[i - 1])
```

I recommend inserting a binding.pry in your conditional, which will allow you to examine the state of your variables as they change through each iteration.. Big help!

Best of luck!